# Conflicting layout-large-hdpi (Nexus 7) with layout-large-hdpi-1280x800 (Samsung 7.7) Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an app for Nexus 4, Samsung 7.7, Nexus 7, S3 and Note-2.
I am making one apk for all these layouts. All are working fine except the Nexus 7 and Samsung 7.7.

I use layout-large-hdpi for Nexus 7 and layout-large-hdpi-1280x800 for Samsung 7.7.
but when I make changes in the Nexus 7 layout it also changes the Samsung 7.7 layout.

I want to put these layouts in one apk, but if I put only Nexus 7 in the apk it shows me the correct layout. When I put the Samsung 7.7 layout also in the apk, the Nexus 7 layout is wrong.

Comment: Please consider re-phrasing the second paragraph. It is very hard to read and understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because Nexus 7 is 1280x800 in size and is XHDPI also. This is the reason Nexus prefers using layout-large-hdpi-1280x800 rather than layout-large-hdpi when both are present. It defines a better selection (choice) for a layout to be opted.

Comment: It would be better to opt for some programmatic approch. Find screen size in inches and use layouts accordindly. if(screensize==7) then use nexus7layout if(screenSize==7.7 use other layout)

Comment: Do you know how to get screen Size in inches?

Comment: For the record, Galaxy Tab 7.7 is mdpi and Nexus 7 is tvdpi. They are both falling back to hdpi since the correct layout doesn't exist.

Comment: TVDPI = XHDPI for nexus7. https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/6eWwQvFGLV8